# character to alphabet numerical value

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, for-loop

Ok so I want to find the numerical value of a character from the alphabet. So a =1, b =2 ..z =26. Below I just called the string password, and I run a `for` loop to set a password array to equal the in the string, so password[1]= a, but because I want the user to enter the string, it could be password[1] = z. anyway, then I run another loop that has a `switch` statement to see if what character it equals to, once the `switch` statement finds that character, it sets the password array to whatever alphabet numerical value is. For some reason, the ending code is 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3, So for some reason its off by 1 value. IDK how this is happening. Can someone help

```
<?php
$password = "aabbccdd";
$password_length = strlen($password);
$password_array = array($password_length); 
$letter= array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

for ($counter = 0; $counter < $password_length; $counter++) {
    $password_array[$counter] = $password{$counter};

    for ($x = 0; $x < 26 ; $x++) {
        switch ($password_array[$counter]) {
            case strtolower($letter[$x]):
                $password_array[$counter] = $x;
                break;
        }
    }
    echo $password_array[$counter];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare the value of `$letter[$x]` with `$password{$counter}` instead of `$password_array[$counter]`. Don't forget to add `$x` by 1 since array index begins with 0.

```
$password = "aabbccdd" ;
$password_length = strlen($password);
$password_array = array($password_length); 
$letter= array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

for($counter = 0; $counter < $password_length; $counter++ ) {
    for($x = 0; $x < 26 ; $x++ ){
        switch ($password{$counter}) {
            case strtolower($letter[$x]):
                $password_array[$counter] = $x + 1;
                break ; 
        }
    }
    echo $password_array[$counter] ; 
}
```

Output

```
11223344
```

Working demo: http://codepad.org/7PT4Z9t3

### Alternative Solution

Your code can be simplified by changing `$letter` to an associative array where each letter would be the key and its numerical value would be the corresponding value. For example, `$letter['a']` would be `1`, `$letter['b']` would be `2`, and so on. Moreover, you only need one `for` loop. See the code below

```
$password = "Aabbccdd" ;
$password_length = strlen($password);
$password_array = array($password_length); 
$letter = array(
 'a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4, 'e'=>5,'f'=>6,'g'=>7,'h'=>8,'i'=>9,'j'=>10,
 'k'=>11,'l'=>12,'m'=>13,'n'=>14,'o'=>15,'p'=>16,'q'=>17,'r'=>18,'s'=>19,'t'=>20,
 'u'=>21,'v'=>22,'w'=>23,'x'=>24,'y'=>25,'z'=>26);

for($counter = 0; $counter < $password_length; $counter++ ) {
    $password_array[$counter] = $letter[strtolower($password{$counter})];
    echo $password_array[$counter] ; 
}
```

Output

```
11223344
```

Working demo: http://codepad.org/E5BgR5Lb

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start at 0, not 1. So $password[1] would equal B, not A

Answer (score 0):

```
$password = "Aabbccdd" ;

$lowercased_password = strtolower($password);
$password_length = strlen($password);
$counter = 0;

while ($counter < $password_length) {
    echo (ord($lowercased_password[$counter])-96);
    $counter++;
}
```

Output:

```
11223344
```

**Some notes:**

- Most of the magic happens with ord() - read up on it here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

**My own thoughts:**

- To be safe, you should add in some validation to ensure that the input *only* contains alphabetical chars.
- Forcing everything to be lowercase reduces password "strength"

  - (If you do decide to allow upercase chars, you will need to make some (very) slight mods to this code)